# Intellij IDEA 2019.2 do not support JAVA EE8

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA 2019.2 do not support JAVA EE8(Java EE plugin), eg CDI2.0, EJB3.2, only support 1.0(JAVA EE6), EJB3.1.

It has problem with xml namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee, involved web.xml, ejb-jar.xml, beans.xml

Comment: Intellij do support Java EE 8 since 2017.3 https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/11/intellij-idea-2017-3-smarter-coding-assistance-better-debugger-run-dashboard-frameworks-support-and-more/. Could you be specific what is the problem you are having with the namespace

Comment: Java EE: CDI plugin
This plugin supports Contexts and Dependency Injection in Java EE 6. The following features are available:
Ability to add CDI support to a project or module.
Ability to download the necessary library files right from within the IDE.
Ability to change the CDI version.

Comment: Java EE 8 Support is Ultimate only feature. Are you using Community edition?